# Getting always extra button on display .. 1 button dont have any ID

Tags: spfx, pnp-js-core, office-ui-fabric-react, loop

I am having problem while looping.

I am always getting an extra button. Please help.

```
{this.state.items.map(myitems1 => {
    return (
       <div key={myitems1.Id}>
           <span>{myitems1.Item_x0020_Name}</span>
           <button onClick={e => this.dosometing(myitems1.Id)}>Offline</button>
       </div>
    );
})}
```

I can see the collection has only three (3) values, But I am getting 4 buttons on screen.

[image]
Getting always extra

Comment: collections started always on index 0, so if you have 3 like 3 items, there are 4 items in collection, so do collection.count-1, otherwise you shoud have 2 (0,1,2) > solution is probably to skip index 0

Comment: ok thank you . Got it .  As I am new .. how can I skip the index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, i am not an spfx man :D : You can also check, if the ItemName is not empty, cause in the first case it is, this is reason why you have only button, not text:

```
{this.state.items.map(myitems1 => {
    if(myitems1.Item_x0020_Name != "")
    {
       return (
          <div key={myitems1.Id}>
              <span>{myitems1.Item_x0020_Name}</span>
              <button onClick={e => this.dosometing(myitems1.Id)}>Offline</button>
          </div>
       );
    }
})}
```

Comment: Oh nice :) You're welcome